# Tooltip resizing in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I got a task that the customer has some data displayed in a tooltip that pops up when clicked.
When opened it shows:

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
Data4
Data5
Data6
```

...

When it has lots of fields the user is able to resize the tooltip and rescale a rectangle like this:

```
Data1 Data2 Data3
Data4 Data5 Data6
```

So, now they want to be displayed like this:

```
Data1 Data3 Data5
Data2 Data4 Data6
```

I'm stuck with this since morning and need some help.

this is the current CSS

```
.tooltip-wrapper {
}

.tooltip-content {

    font-family: AvertaRegular;

    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #FFFFFF;

    .tooltip-real-content {
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -14px;
        left: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin-left: 28px;
        border-left: 0 solid transparent;
        border-right: 14px solid transparent;
        border-top: 14px solid #FFFFFF;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    a.close-button {
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        top: -12px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        padding: 0px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        font-size: 0px;
        line-height: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        z-index: 3;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 18px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);

        &:after, &:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 9px;
            left: 6px;
            width: 8px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #397DBA;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        &:before {
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }

        &:after {
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }

    }

    .inner-content-wrapper {
        min-width: 210px;
        width: 210px;
        max-width: 650px;
        max-height: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 12px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        resize: auto;
        transition: .2s;

        .pictoDisplay {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: wrap;
            min-width: 190px;
            max-width: 100%;
            min-height: 170px;
            max-height: 100%;
        }
        .infoDisplay {
            display: block;
            width: 210px;
        }

        .inner-content {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden !important;
            outline: 0;
            text-align: left;

            .infowindow_template_geom_qt {
                span {
                    margin: 5px 0;
                    display: block;
                }
            }

            h4 {
                display: block;
                width: 190px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-weight: 700;
                font-family: AvertaRegular;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                line-height: 120%;
                color: #CCCCCC;
                font-size: 11px;
            }

            p {
                color: #333333;
                display: block;
                width: 190px;
                max-width: 190px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 0 7px;
                font-family: AvertaRegular;
                font: 400 13px AvertaRegular;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }

        }

    }

    .tip-container {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -20px;
        left: -4px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 16px;
        margin-left: 28px;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 0;

        &:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            left: 0;
            top: -10px;
            margin-left: 0;
            transform: skew(0, -45deg);
            border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
            z-index: 0;
        }
    }
}

.selectFilterContainer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.imageContainer {
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 22px;

    image {
        width: 22px;
    }
}

.infowindow_template_cuota_descr
.infowindow_template_geom_descr,
.infowindow_template_geom_qt,
.infowindow_template_pictos_data {
    font-family: AvertaRegular;
}

.infowindow_template_cuota_descr {
    padding: 1px;
}

.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

div.notes {
    input {
        font-size: 11px;
        width: 122px;
    }

    h4 {
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }
}

.confirmButton {
    border: 0;
    background-color: #15A4FA;
    font-family: AvertaBold;
    font-size: 9.5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 22px;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 54px;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #50BDFF;
    }
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

:host ::ng-deep mat-icon {
    &.edit {
        font-size: 16px;
        float: right;
        color: #15A4FA;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    &.save-edit, &.cancel-edit {
        width: 20px;
        padding-top: 4px;
    }

    &.cancel-edit {
        color: rgb(201, 51, 51);
    }
}

input.editBox {
    width: 75%;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

file

Comment: Could you please provide a running example?

Comment: Look into using columns https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: @heaxyh Sure, here is how it is right now:

https://codepen.io/vendra00/pen/abRVZXv

Comment: You should try with [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)

Comment: "*So, now they want to be displayed like...[3x2 grid]*" - always like that? Or only if there's more than a set number of items? What are the constraints?

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to limit number of rows and let columns expand dynamically. From your code I have commented your `grid-template-columns` and added the `grid-template-rows` to 2 rows and for ordering them check `grid-auto-flow`.

```css
/* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr)); */
/* Not for your requirement */
  
grid-auto-flow: column dense; /* auto flow dense only for columns */
grid-template-rows: 3em 3em; /* 2 rows */
```

Please check the below snippet

```css
.trigger-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.trigger-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip-container {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.trigger-checkbox:checked+.tooltip {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip ul {
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));*/
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
  grid-template-rows: 3em 3em;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tooltip li {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-container">
  <label for="tooltip-checkbox" class="trigger-label">Click me to see the tooltip</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="tooltip-checkbox" class="trigger-checkbox">
  <div class="tooltip">
    <ul>
      <li>data1</li>
      <li>data2</li>
      <li>data3</li>
      <li>data4</li>
      <li>data5</li>
      <li>data6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```